# Possible to stream video over 115kbps?

Tags: ios, ipad, video, ffmpeg

I need some advice from people experienced with streaming video.

I have a task to put together a system that allows video coming from RS-170 (composite) video cameras and have them displayed on an iPad.  The catch is that no wireless (no Wi-Fi, no bluetooth) is allowed.  Only a wired interface.

The physical I/O options on an iPad are apparently extremely limited, but I did manage to come across a company named Redpark that makes an RS232-to-Lightning cable.  So my proposed solution is to have the video feeds go into a box with software that digitizes and encodes the video, and then sends it over RS232 to the iPad using that cable.  The catch here is that the maximum bandwidth on that cable is 115kbps.

My preliminary testing of this setup on a prototype system have been less than stellar so far.  I set up two PCs, each with serial ports, and hooked them together with a null modem.  I then set the baud rates of the ports to 115kpbs and then attempted to stream a web cam video feed over the serial connection in real-time using ffmpeg.  The results weren't very encouraging, but I at least did manage to get some sort of image to show up.

I guess I need to play around with the ffmpeg encoding options some more.  But I need to ask: am I wasting my time with this idea, or should what I am asking here be possible?

Answer (score 0):

For [SDA](http://speeddemosarchive.com) LQ standard ("low quality") we encode H.264 mp4 (using x264) with a 128 kbps video track. The hardware decoding on the iPad can play it. It is maximum 320x240 30 fps video. The quality depends heavily on the material. For mostly nonmoving material, it is watchable. If there is a lot of movement or lighting changes, you may not be able to make out much. You can check out some examples at the link. Video game video, but some may be comparable to your application.

Without knowing more about your requirements (resolution, framerate, type of material), it is difficult to say more. However, given the right material, it is definitely possible to do it and have it be watchable (for some definitions of watchable).